# excel service rest api is unauthorized but list rest api is authorized in sharepoint online

Tags: rest, api, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Can anyone please answer why below is authorized:

https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/APTest/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Deputies')/items

but

https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/APTest/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/TestDocLibrary/ProjectBudgetTracker.xlsm/model/Ranges('DashBoard!J6')

is unauthorized in Fiddler for same sharepoint site collection.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

> The Excel Services REST API applies to SharePoint and SharePoint 2016
>   on-premises. For Office 365 Education, Business, and Enterprise
>   accounts, use the Excel REST APIs that are part of the Microsoft Graph
>   endpoint.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sample-uri-for-excel-services-rest-api